# Search for words in a web page and replace them

Tags: php

I am trying to make a translation service for my website.

The language the user wants to read it in is stored in `$languageCode` (for example `fr`).

I then have a table called `translations` in a database that has four columns:

- `ID` - primary key for each translation
- `toTranslate` - text that is searched for in the document
- `parentID` - the value of `toTranslate`'s parent element (to avoid confusion between two sets of the same text with different translations)
- `translation` - text that `toTranslate` is replaced by.
- `language` - which language is the text translated in (language code eg. fr)

I would like to know...

- how to search text in a document for a text string that matches `toTranslate` and who's parent element's `id` matches `parentID`.
- how to replace that text with the given translation

An example:

```
<h1 id="heading">My website</h1>
<div id="paragraph">
    Welcome to my website!
</div>
```

Database:

```
1 > "My website" > "heading" > "Mon site internet" > "fr"

2 > "Welcome to my website!" > "paragraph" > "Bienvenue sur mon site web!" > "fr"

3 > "My website" > "heading" > "Mi sitio web" > "sp"

4 > "Welcome to my website!" > "paragraph" > "¡Bienvenidos a mi sitio web!" > "sp"
```

Please lead me in the right direction with regards to php functions / methods and how each module would work together. If you can, please include an example.

Comment: Have a look at [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domxpath.php) and the examples there.

Comment: I know this is not the answer to your question, but...
There is a easier approach when it comes to translations for your own website: simply replace the text that needs translation by a function like $mytext->get('home','heading'); Then simply set language in your $mytext object on creation. Let the $mytext object fetch the text from DB or so ) I can go more into detail if this is what you are looking for ?

Comment: @minychillo that sounds quite like what I am looking for, please elaborate with an example in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplify here, but you get the drift:

```
<?php

    class mytext {

      private $lang;

      function __construct( $lang ){
        $this->lang = $lang;
      }

      function get( $key ){

        // key can be anything here as long as it is unique
        // you could go with something like "/mywebsite/heading"


        // fetch data from db, with something like this 
        // select text from translationTable where id = $key AND language = $this->lang

        return $dbResult['text'];
      }

    }


    $mytext = new mytext('fr');
    ?>

    <h1 id="heading"><?=$mytext->get('/mywebsite/heading')?></h1>
    <div id="paragraph">
        <?=$mytext->get('/mywebsite/paragraph')?>
    </div>
```